# All morphisms of k-schemes between $\mathbb{P}_k^1$ and $\mathbb{P}_k^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes

I'm reading section 6.3 of Vakil FOAG. In it he defines a morphism of $k$-schemes $X,Y$ as a morphism of schemes that commutes with the maps $X\longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec} k$ and $Y\longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec} k$.

I'm struggling with this concept in practice; for example, how does one find all the morphisms of $k$-schemes between $\mathbb{P}_k^1$ and $\mathbb{P}_k^1$?

We want to form a commutative diagram with morphisms going to $\operatorname{Spec} k$, which is $0$. So I feel like this should be easy, but how to proceed?

Comment: Maybe the affine case would be easier to think about? See if you can figure out all the self maps of $\mathbb A^1_k$.

Comment: Please use \operatorname{Spec} to format $\operatorname{Spec}$: this produces a better look and spacing. I've made the upgrade in your post for you this time. Next, for the problem at hand, maps to projective space are classified by line bundles - this is mentioned in 6.3.12, with a reference to theorem 16.4.1. Have you checked this out?

Comment: One family of such maps is informally given by $[x : y] \mapsto [x^n : y^n]$ for some $n \ge 0$.  Another family is that any automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ is given by $[x : y] \mapsto [ax + by : cx + dy]$ for some $a,b,c,d \in k$ with $ad - bc \ne 0$.  (I don't know off the top of my head whether compositions of these examples give all possible morphisms.)

Comment: Every morphism $\mathbb{P}^1_k \to \mathbb{P}^1_k$ is given by $[x : y] \mapsto [g(x, y) : f(x, y)]$ where $g, f$ are homogeneous polynomials over $k$ of the same degree and both are nonzero. This is the same as the classification of endomorphisms of the function field $k(t)$ over $k$ where $t = \frac{y}{x}$ (the corresponding endomorphism sends $t$ to $\frac{f}{g}$). You should be able to do it by arguing via the standard affine cover by two copies of $\mathbb{A}^1$. As Asvin says, it might be a good idea to work out $\mathbb{A}^1$ as a warmup.

Comment: How precisely do those commute with the maps to Spec k

Comment: In order to have a map $X \to \operatorname{Spec} k$, it's equivalent to giving a ring homomorphism $k \to \Gamma(X, \mathscr{O}_X)$ - and you often end up thinking of the image as being "constant" functions on $X$.  Then, giving a morphism of $k$-schemes can be thought of as asking that for any $\lambda \in k$, the "constant function" $\lambda$ on $Y$ pulls back to the "constant function" $\lambda$ on $X$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan ok thank you I understand that now. Now my confusion is how one can show that no other maps also satisfy this